# Android - How to store array of classes in res xml

Tags: android, arrays, class, typedarray

I want to store list of classes inside an xml on my res, so I can use it globally just using the index.

```
<resources>
    <array name="array_class">
        <class>Dashboard.class</class>
    </array>
</resources>
```

in my activity

```
int index = x; // i get the the index from database
TypedArray arrayClass = getActivity().getResources()
        .(R.array.array_class);
Class myClass = (Class) arrayClass.getString(index);
```

It throw me an error, cannot cast String to Class.
Yeah I know, I cannot do that. So how the correct way to store array of classes on res? or any alternative way to call Class[] value globally??

Comment: If you find my answer is helpful then please vote for it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside your resource file store full name of all classes including package name

```
<resources>
    <array name="array_class">
        <class>com.example.Dashboard</class>
        <class>com.example.YourOtherClass</class>
    </array>
</resources>
```

Then in Java code, you can retrieve by the following method

```
try {
    int index = x; // i get the the index from database
    TypedArray arrayClass = getActivity().getResources().(R.array.array_class);
    Class<?> act = Class.forName(arrayClass.getString(index));
} catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Hope it helps